# How to recover from a boot hang after deleting old swap?

Tags: fedora, boot, partition, swap, lvm

I did a fresh installation of Fedora 20 in the free space of my hard drive after failing to upgrade from the older version. Everything seems to be working fine until I deleted the partition containing the older version to free up some space. Upon restarting the computer, I got the following message after waiting for a long time:

> Warning: Could not boot
>
> Warning: /dev/fedora_old/swap does not exist
>
> Starting Dracut Emergency Shell

I am still able to boot if I type `exit` on dracut prompt. But, that does not solve the root of the problem. There are a [few suggestions](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/32450/fedora-19-dracut-swap-does-not-exist-boot-error/) on the web proposing:

```
dracut --force --regenerate-all
```

I am not sure what it does exactly and it [doesn't seem to resolve](http://web3us.com/drupal6/node/320) the problem. What is the proper way to sort out the swap partition? It seems that the swap for the older OS was being used when the new OS is being installed despite it having its own swap partition.

And how could I avoid such a problem in the future?

This is what I have for `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora_new-root00 /          ext4    defaults                   1 1
UUID=somehexdec               /boot      ext4    defaults                   1 2
UUID=someotherhexdec          /boot/efi  vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/fedora_new-home00 /home      ext4    defaults                   1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora_new-swap   swap       swap    defaults                   0 0
```

Comment: did you edit your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @bersch, no, I didn't edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that manually editing out the parameter containing `rd.lvm.lv=fedora_old/swap` in the grub configuration file does the trick. There is no need to run dracut or reinstall grub at all.

```
# vi /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Search for the following line under the menu entry which you will be booting from:

> linuxefi /vmlinuz-3.12.x-xxx.fc20.x86_64
>   root=/dev/mapper/fedora_new-root00 ro <strike>rd.lvm.lv=fedora_old/swap</strike>
>   rd.lvm.lv=fedora_new/swap vconsole.font=....

To make sure the above changes stick, do the same for `/etc/default/grub`:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="<strike>rd.lvm.lv=fedora_old/swap</strike> rd.lvm.lv=fedora_new/swap
>   vconsole.font=...

Please provide an answer or leave a comment if this method is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

To make this permanent, you'll want to update `/etc/default/grub` to point to the correct swap partition.

Example:
Change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rootVG/root rd.lvm.lv=oldnameVG/swapLV rhgb quiet"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rootVG/root rd.lvm.lv=rootVG/swapLV rhgb quiet"
```

When that is completed, you 'll want to regenerate the grub config:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

You can verify that it worked by looking at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and verifying that swap is now pointed at the correct VG/LV

Comment: Is running `grub2-mkconfig` **mandatory** and/or **required**?